# Dynamically adding complex objects to the gridview

Tags: android, arrays, gridview, addition, dynamically-generated

I'm learning custom adapters, I understand the principle: create a list, fill in the data, connect the adapter - list is displayed. I figured out how to add a new string if the list consists of strings.
Tell me how to add a new item (a new image and a new string in one), if I use a GridView, consisting of images with strings.
In Google, all examples are either without adding complex items (only one string) or without adding dynamically

upd: I'll explain by an example what I need. The code creates a list of items or simply items are placed in layout, then in the running program the user clicks on one of the objects - and in the other part of the activity an object with the same content is created (preferably with content that can be edited before creation). Or am I wrong and need to use constructions from layouts? With a lot of it is difficult visually for the code, and reduces performance compared to gridview, listview

Comment: It sounds like you need a view (XML) that represents each data entry (image + string value).

Comment: https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/third_party/material-components-android/demos/codelabs/building-beautiful-apps/complete/app/src/main/java/io/material/demo/codelab/buildingbeautifulapps/MainActivity.java take a look at the google iosched app for a good example of an adapter that has both text and images.

Comment: I explained the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are trying to implement here is a listfragment, I hope I can help here:

**1:** Create a `list_item.xml` file that contains your list item (for example, `ImageView` and a `TextView`), this will represent a single item in the list/grid

**2:** create a Model class that represent your item

```
class Image{
   Bitmap imageBitmap;
   String title;
}
```

**3:** pass the model to the adapter as a list

**4:** in the Adapter, in the `getView()` method:

- inflate the `list_item.xml`
- `findViewById()` for each view you have in the `list_item.xml`
  like so: 
  `(TextView) View.findViewById(android.R.id.textView))
                    .setText(getItem(position);`
- the `getItem(position)` part will fill the view with data from the list you passed to model

a final look of the adapter would look like:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Image> images =new ArrayList<>();
    Context c;

    //constructor
    public MyAdapter(List<Image> images, Context c) {
        this.images.addAll(images);
        this.c = c;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return images.get(i);
    }

    @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
          if (convertView == null) {
              convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
          }

          ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.textView))
                  .setText(getItem(position).getTitle());

          ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.imageView))
                  .setImageBitmap(getItem(position).getImageBitmap());

          return convertView;
      }

}
```

Comment: If I correctly understood your answer - it's just just a dynamic addition of object structures from a pre-created list. More precisely, the transfer of the pre-recorded data to the new list is unchanged. For example: in the code the list of lines / images was created, then in the running application this list is transferred to listview.

Comment: sorry, before we start a long conversation to understand each other, **I advise you to do more research** on `ListView` and **the way it works.** I know working with ListView for the first time can be difficult, but eventually you will get it. there are plenty of examples and documentations on the internet. also the Adapter I wrote is a very basic example to start with, good luck.